# Can I require a controller, in a directive, set with ng-controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have (sort of) the following html:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
       <my-sub-directive></my-sub-directive>
    </div>
```

how the controller looks is not important:

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
   $scope.foo = "bar";
})
```

and my directive looks like this:

```
function mySubDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl:"aTemplate.html",
            require: "^MyController",
            link: function($scope, element) {

            }
        };
    }
app.directive("mySubDirective", mySubDirective);
```

In the documentation they always specify another directive in the `require`-property, but it says that it means you require the controller. So I wanted to try this solution.  However I get the error

"Controller 'MyController', required by directive 'mySubDirective', can't be found".

Is it not possible to require a controller from the directive if it is set by ng-controller?

Comment: `require` is supposed to contain name of the directive, not a name of the controller. But I doubt it will work with ngController (but you can give it a try). However much better approach is to use [`controller as`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example) syntax, i.e. placing the controller instance on the scope.

Comment: `require` is to use the `controller` declared within the other directive.

Comment: So what i'm attempting here, "requiring" a controller declared with ng-controller, is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do:

```
require: "^ngController"
```

So, you can't be more specific than that, i.e. you can't ask for `"MainCtrl"` or `"MyController"` by name, but it will get you the controller instance:

```
.controller("SomeController", function(){
   this.doSomething = function(){
     //
   };
})

.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    require: "?^ngController",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
      if (ctrl && ctrl.doSomething){
        ctrl.doSomething();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
   <foo></foo>
</div>
```

I don't think, though, that this is a good approach, since it makes the directive very dependent on *where* it is used. You could follow\ the recommendation in the comments to pass the controller instance directly - it makes it somewhat more explicit:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController as ctrl">
  <foo ctrl="ctrl"></foo>
</div>
```

but it still is a too generic of an object and could easily be misused by users of your directive.

Instead, expose a well-defined API (via attributes) and pass references to functions/properties defined in the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController as ctrl">
  <foo do="ctrl.doSomething()"></foo>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up with something like your last suggestion, only i added the function on the scope. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Gustav, how is it different from the last suggestion? Last suggestion *is* adding function `doSomething` on the scope

Comment: Oh, I mean I didn't use the "ctrl as"-syntax and have the function on the controller. I put it directly on $scope and didn't really have anything in the html. I don't know if it is a bit "old fashioned". I haven't adapted the "ctrl as"-syntax just yet.

Comment: @Gustav, for all intents and purposes of this question, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`element.controller()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) in the directive link function to test the closest controller specified by `ngController`. A limitation of this method is that it doesn't tell you which controller it is. There are probably several ways you can do it, but I'm opting to name the controller constructor, and expose it in the scope, so you can use `instanceof`

```
// Deliberately not adding to global scope
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('my-app', []);

  // Exposed in so can do "instanceof" in directive
  function MyController($scope) {}
  app.controller('MyController', MyController);

  app.directive("foo", function(){
    return {
      link: function($scope, $element){
        var controller = $element.controller();

        // True or false depending on whether the closest 
        // ngController is a MyController
        console.log(controller instanceof MyController);
      }
    };
  })

})();
```

You can see this at http://plnkr.co/edit/AVmr7Eb7dQD70Mpmhpjm?p=preview

However, this won't work if you have nested `ngController`s, and you want to test for one that isn't necessarily the closest. For that, you can defined a recursive function to walk up the DOM tree:

```
  app.directive("foo", function(){

    function getAncestorController(element, controllerConstructor) {
      var controller = element.controller();
      if (controller instanceof controllerConstructor) {
        return controller;
      } else if (element.parent().length) {
        return getAncestorController(element.parent(), controllerConstructor);
      } else {
        return void(0); // undefined
      }
    }

    return {
      link: function(scope, element){
        var controller = getAncestorController(element, MyController);

        // The ancestor controller instance, or undefined
        console.log(controller);
      }
    };
  })
```

You can see this at http://plnkr.co/edit/xM5or4skle62Y9UPKfwG?p=preview

For reference the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) state that the `controller` function can be used to find controllers specified with `ngController`:

> By default retrieves controller associated with the ngController directive

Comment: I don't think `element.controller("MyController")` works as you think it does: http://plnkr.co/edit/zPeCNH3F2H2Fp7lxU3Kj?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev You're absolutely right... thanks! I have edited my answer to suggest a slightly different method, but still using `element.controller`

Comment: So, really, it's not different than `require: "^ngController"` - just more verbose

Comment: @NewDev You're right again! Feeling sheepish now... However, if you have nested `ngControllers` (not commenting on if that's a good idea or not), then you can't use `require` to find anything but the closest one. I've edited my answer with a function that walks up the tree to find one that might not be the closest.